# How do I create a column based on a change in factor varible in another column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following dataframe containing information for spending levels in each county across time, and the stay at home requirements for the county. The stay at home requirements are from 0 to 2 with 2 indicating a stricter lockdown:

```
# A tibble: 47,898 x 4
   countyfips date     C6_Stay_at_home_requirements spend_all
        <dbl> <chr>                           <dbl>     <dbl>
 1       1001 20200112                            0  -0.0831 
 2       1001 20200119                            0   0.0038 
 3       1001 20200126                            0   0.0917 
 4       1001 20200202                            0  -0.00724
 5       1001 20200209                            0   0.00567
 6       1001 20200216                            0   0.125  
 7       1001 20200223                            0  -0.0929 
 8       1001 20200301                            0  -0.0455 
 9       1001 20200308                            0   0.108  
10       1001 20200315                            0   0.212  
# … with 47,888 more rows
```

I would like to create a new column called WeekAfterReopening1to0 which would be 0 at the point where the policy is eased from 1 to 0. The column would then increase in value by one each week. Before the reopening though, I would like to have negative numbers. In the case that there was not a change in the county from 2 to 0, for example, then there would be NA for all values.

Then I would like to do a similar thing if the variable went from 2 to 0 and if it went from 2 to 1, just with different column names (WeekAfterReopening2to0 and WeekAfterReopening2to1).

The end result could look something like this:

```
# A tibble: 47,898 x 6
   countyfips date     C6_Stay_at_home_requirements WeekAfterReopening2to1 WeekAfterReopening1to0 WeekAfterReopening2to0
        <dbl> <chr>                           <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>                <dbl>
 1       1001 20200112                            0    -3        -5                 NA
 2       1001 20200119                            2    -2        -4                 NA
 3       1001 20200126                            2    -1        -3                 NA                        
 4       1001 20200202                            1     0        -2                 NA
 5       1001 20200209                            1     1        -1                 NA
 6       1001 20200216                            0     2        0                  NA
 7       1001 20200223                            0     3        1                  NA
 8       1001 20200301                            0     4        2                  NA
 9       1001 20200308                            0     5        3                  NA
10       1001 20200315                            0     6        4                  NA
# … with 47,888 more rows
```

I was thinking of using dplyr functions mutate, and arrange but I don't know how to put the functions together, as I think it is beyond my r Capabilities.

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, this can be done in the following way:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Reopening1to0 = (C6_Stay_at_home_requirements == 0) & (lag(C6_Stay_at_home_requirements, default = -1) == 1),
         WeekAfterReopening1to0 = row_number() - which.max(Reopening1to0))
```

First for every row we check whether the `C6_Stay_at_home_requirements` column has value 0 and its predecessor had value 1. Then, we subtract the current row number from the row number that has a `TRUE` value on that newly created column, thus finding how many rows that is away from the current row.
This could be combined into one line, but I think it is clearer this way.

Which gives

```
   countyfips     date C6_Stay_at_home_requirements spend_all Reopening1to0 WeekAfterReopening1to0
1        1001 20200112                            0  -0.08310         FALSE                     -5
2        1001 20200119                            2   0.00380         FALSE                     -4
3        1001 20200126                            2   0.09170         FALSE                     -3
4        1001 20200202                            1  -0.00724         FALSE                     -2
5        1001 20200209                            1   0.00567         FALSE                     -1
6        1001 20200216                            0   0.12500          TRUE                      0
7        1001 20200223                            0  -0.09290         FALSE                      1
8        1001 20200301                            0  -0.04550         FALSE                      2
9        1001 20200308                            0   0.10800         FALSE                      3
10       1001 20200315                            0   0.21200         FALSE                      4
```

Input data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "countyfips date     C6_Stay_at_home_requirements spend_all
1       1001 20200112                            0  -0.0831 
2       1001 20200119                            2   0.0038 
3       1001 20200126                            2   0.0917 
4       1001 20200202                            1  -0.00724
5       1001 20200209                            1   0.00567
6       1001 20200216                            0   0.125  
7       1001 20200223                            0  -0.0929 
8       1001 20200301                            0  -0.0455 
9       1001 20200308                            0   0.108  
10       1001 20200315                            0   0.212")
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should probably group the data by countyfips right?

Comment: Yes, you can `group_by` before the `mutate`!

Comment: Hi, I have tried the following code ``` Affinity_County_Weekly.csv %>%
  group_by(countyfips) %>%
  arrange(date) %>% 
  mutate(Reopening1to0 = (C6_Stay_at_home_requirements == 0) & (lag(C6_Stay_at_home_requirements, default = -1) == 1),
         WeekAfterReopening1to0 = row_number() - which.max(Reopening1to0)) ``` and the console displays the error: ```Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `WeekAfterReopening1to0`.
x Input `WeekAfterReopening1to0` can't be recycled to size 27.
ℹ Input `WeekAfterReopening1to0` is `row_number() - which.max(Reopening1to0)`. ```

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. Could you a part your data that goes wrong, using `dput()`? You can edit your original question to use that data.

Comment: I have looked at the data and the problem is that the county lacks the C6 variable (there are just NA values). I guess that I would need to include some NA.omit function? Again, I am unsure about how precisely to do that.

Comment: You can do `filter(!is.na(C6))` if you want to remove NA values, or `replace_na(list(C6 = 0))` if you want to replace them with 0, for example.

Comment: Hi, removing the NAs worked but unfortunately the code returns FALSE for every column. There might be a problem with the lag function, what do you think?
{
 x %>% filter( Reopening1to0 == TRUE, Reopening2to0 == TRUE, Reopening2to1 == TRUE)
# A tibble: 0 x 134
}

Comment: Filtering like that, with commas, means that all the parts have to be true. There is no row for which `Reopening1to0`, `Reopening2to0` AND `Reopening2to1` are all true (there can't be). Instead, you want to separate them with `|` to create an 'or': `filter(Reopening1to0 == TRUE | Reopening2to0 == TRUE | Reopening2to1 == TRUE)`

Comment: You are right but the problem remains, there is FALSE for every row in every one of the three columns. 
x %>% filter(Reopening1to0 == TRUE | Reopening2to0 == TRUE | Reopening2to1 == TRUE)
# A tibble: 0 x 134

Comment: You could try replacing `lag` with `dplyr::lag`, since otherwise it might use `stats::lag`.

Comment: No problem. Please mark the answer as accepted if it answered your question.